# wp_list_comments function and says text wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can i change the text, after comment author name is in output of wp_list_comments
function in WordPress ?

 Default value is "says:" but i just need to insert my text in that. I have done that with CSS and display:none.But it does not look nice

Answer (score 0):

you can remove or change the "says" from comment list as add the following class and function into your theme functions.php

```
    class Comment_Says_Custom_Text_Wrangler {
        function comment_says_text($translation, $text, $domain) {
        $new_says = ''; //whatever you want to have instead of 'says' in comments
        $translations = &get_translations_for_domain( $domain );
        if ( $text == '<cite class="fn">%s</cite> <span class="says">says:</span>' ) {
           if($new_says) $new_says = ' '.$new_says; //compensate for the space character
           return $translations->translate( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite><span class="says">'.$new_says.':</span>' );
         } else {
        return $translation; // standard text
         }  
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code `add_filter('gettext', array('Comment_Says_Custom_Text_Wrangler', 'comment_says_text'), 10, 4);` should be added to the code:

```
class Comment_Says_Custom_Text_Wrangler {
            function comment_says_text($translation, $text, $domain) {
            $new_says = ''; //whatever you want to have instead of 'says' in comments
        $translations = &get_translations_for_domain( $domain );
        if ( $text == '<cite class="fn">%s</cite> <span class="says">says:</span>' ) {
               if($new_says) $new_says = ' '.$new_says; //compensate for the space character
           return $translations->translate( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite><span class="says">'.$new_says.':</span>' );
         } else {
        return $translation; // standard text
             }  
            }
    }
    add_filter('gettext', array('Comment_Says_Custom_Text_Wrangler', 'comment_says_text'), 10, 4);
```